# Microsoft word file deleted itself - On a USB stick

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, microsoft-word

There was a Microsoft word file that I've been writing on which was in a USB. I've been writing on this file on a desktop which is Windows 7 and I guess the Microsoft Word version is 2007 on that pc. Then I connected the USB to my laptop which is windows 10 probably including an advanced version of Microsoft Word. As soon as I clicked the file, Windows gave me this error: 'Sorry, we couldn't find your file. Was it moved, renamed or deleted?' And then I literally saw the file disappeared, 1 second after the error, the file was gone. Could anyone help me please I really need to recover that file. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Golden rule: Never keep the only copy of anything on something as prone to sudden failure as a USB stick, SD card etc. What happens if you put it back in the other computer?

Comment: Working within Word on a document on a flash drive is the number one cause of document corruption and data loss. • Do not open a document on a flash drive from Word or with Word.
• Do not save a document to a flash drive from within Word.
• Do not print a Word document while it is on a flash drive.

Comment: @Tetsujin I've tried that and I couldn't see the file on the other computer either.

Comment: So, isn't there any possible solution to recover that file? Just a few precautions for the next times then.

Comment: You're probably down to recovery/scavenger software.

Comment: For those experiencing the same problem, I've been able to recover the file by using software, I've used two different ones and both have done the same work. They've recovered the file the way I saved them approximately 15 hours ago which means the last changes are not saved.

Comment: Before you try recovery software or do *anything* else with the USB drive, make an image, lest an attempt to recover the file causes more harm. https://www.howtogeek.com/446176/how-to-create-an-image-of-your-usb-drive/

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to look for deleted files in temporary files and system caches, but it is really not recommended that you put the only files in the USB. Also you can search for some software to recover files, but it may be for a fee.